# Test login Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, junit, mockito

I tried to test my login servlet using mockito, but it return the error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.PrintWriter.println(String)" because "out" is null.
> at control.LoginPatient.doPost(LoginPatient.java:55)
> at control.LoginPatientTest.testDoPostSuccessfull(LoginPatientTest.java:64)

Here the code of my Login servlet:

```
package control;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import model.ProfileManager;
import model.Bean.UserBean;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginPatient
 */
@WebServlet("/LoginPatient")
public class LoginPatient extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public LoginPatient() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String fiscal_code=request.getParameter("fiscal_code");
        String user_password= request.getParameter("user_password");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        ProfileManager pM=new ProfileManager();
        UserBean patient= pM.ReturnPatientByKey(fiscal_code, user_password);

        if(patient != null) {
            HttpSession session= request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute( "user" , patient);
            session.setMaxInactiveInterval(-1);
            out.println("1");
        }

        else {
            out.println("0"); 
        }
    }

}
```

and here my test case:

```
class LoginPatientTest {

    private LoginPatient loginPatient;
    private HttpServletRequest mockedRequest;
    private HttpServletResponse mockedResponse;
    private ServletContext mockedServletContext;
    private HttpSession mockedSession;
    private PatientBean patient;
    private ProfileManager pm;
    private PrintWriter mockedOut;
    
    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
        loginPatient = new LoginPatient();
        mockedRequest = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        mockedResponse = Mockito.mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
        mockedSession = Mockito.mock(HttpSession.class);
        mockedServletContext = Mockito.mock(ServletContext.class);
        mockedOut = Mockito.mock(PrintWriter.class);
        patient = Mockito.mock(PatientBean.class);
        pm = Mockito.mock(ProfileManager.class);
    }

    /**
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     */
    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    /**
     * Test method for {@link control.LoginPatient#doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)}.
     * @throws javax.servlet.ServletException
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */ 
    @Test
    final void testDoPostSuccessful() throws ServletException, IOException{
        
Mockito.doReturn(mockedServletContext).when(mockedRequest).getServletContext();
        Mockito.when(mockedRequest.getParameter("fiscal_code")).thenReturn("fiscalCode");
        Mockito.when(mockedRequest.getParameter("user_password")).thenReturn("password");
        Mockito.when(mockedRequest.getSession()).thenReturn(mockedSession);
        Mockito.when(pm.ReturnPatientByKey("fiscalCode", "password"));
        Mockito.when(mockedResponse.getWriter()).thenReturn(mockedOut);

loginPatient.doPost(mockedRequest, mockedResponse);

        Mockito.verify(mockedOut).println("1");
        Mockito.verify(mockedSession).setAttribute(Mockito.eq("user"), patient);
    }

}
```

*I don't use Spring*

Update: Now it gives me another error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
> Invalid use of argument matchers!
> 2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
> -> at control.LoginPatientTest.testDoPostSuccessful(LoginPatientTest.java:75)
> This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
> //incorrect:
> someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
> When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
> For example:
> //correct:
> someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
> For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
> at control.LoginPatientTest.testDoPostSuccessful(LoginPatientTest.java:75)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
> at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:205)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:201)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:141)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue 1:**

In the mock setup change mockedOut variable to  `mockedOut = Mockito.mock(PrintWriter.class);`

**Issue 2:**

You mocked out `mockedOut` variable after you fires the business logic.
You should change the order. Mock everything before the business logic is invoked.

```
//Given

    Mockito.doReturn(mockedServletContext).when(mockedRequest).getServletContext();
    Mockito.when(mockedRequest.getParameter("fiscal_code")).thenReturn("fiscalCode");
    Mockito.when(mockedRequest.getParameter("user_password")).thenReturn("password");
    Mockito.when(mockedRequest.getSession()).thenReturn(mockedSession);
    Mockito.when(pm.ReturnPatientByKey("fiscalCode", "password"));
    Mockito.when(mockedResponse.getWriter()).thenReturn(mockedOut);

//When   
    loginPatient.doPost(mockedRequest, mockedResponse);   


//Then
    Mockito.verify(mockedOut).println("1");
    Mockito.verify(mockedSession).setAttribute(Mockito.eq("user"), patient);
```

Comment: I tried to change the order and set it as you wrote, but it always gives me the same error. @tomeszmh

Comment: Please provide your servlet implementation

Comment: It's already present in the question. Under the heading "my login servlet". @tomeszmh

Comment: I need the whole class, not just a method.

Comment: I posted the whole class . @tomeszmh

Comment: Thank you but now it gives me another error. Please see my updated question if you can. @tomeszmh

Comment: I don't know what is in line 75, you did not mention it, but if my answer solves the issue, you should accept it. Your next question should be solved in another post.

Comment: Mockito.verify(mockedSession).setAttribute(Mockito.eq("user"), patient); this is line 75. Ok,  thank you